# What are the classical attestions of "duodeviginti" and "undeviginti"?

Tags: resource-request, numbers, source

Calling eighteen and nineteen "two from twenty" and "one from twenty" has always felt like a bit of joke to me, especially since modern uses of Latin and all her daughter languages use the "expected" "ten and eight" and "ten and nine", in some order, instead. Thus my question: What classical attestations actually exist for duodeviginti and undeviginti as opposed to octodecim and novemdecim?

Trying to find them myself online has not borne fruit, and I do not have physical access to any classical Latin sources myself, only student texts that blithely state the fact without justification.

Comment: Most of the daughter languages do _not_ use anything like _octodecim_ and _novemnecim_, but have replaced seventeen onwards with the reverse structure, derived from _decim-septem_, _decim-octo_,  decim_novem_.

Comment: Accuracy aside, I think there's a good question here: if you want to figure out where a particular word is used, how do you find that? I've given one answer (a corpus search) but someone explaining how to consult Lewis and Short would also be good.

Comment: @ColinFine yeah, that's a good point. Sorry for the incorrect generalization. Still, none of them use anything like "two from twenty"

Comment: You're right, none of them use those forms. But I find it interesting that so many languages "change gear" somewhere in the teens: Classical Latin changed at 18, most Romance languages change at 16 or 17, Germanic languages change at 13, and traditional Welsh changes at 15, with an outlier for 18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Packard corpus shows [16 results for undeviginti](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=undeviginti) and [34 for duodeviginti](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=duodeviginti).

Notably, it also shows [2 for octodecim](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=octodecim), though zero for novemdecim.

Meanwhile, [septemdecim gets 20 hits](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=septemdecim), showing us about how many we should expect for a number like this.

Comment: [There are 36 results](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=undevi&first=21) if you allow for adjective/adverb forms like *undevice(n)simus*, *undevicie(n)s*, and *undeviceni*

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I'll wait another day and a few cursory experiments of my own before accepting. Once I'm back in front of a proper computer I'll definitely be adding this tool to my bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

"*Undeviginti*" is attested at Livy "*The History of Rome*", book 30, chapter 9: "*Claudius triremes quadriremesque et **undeviginti** hominum milia armavit*".